# updateSelectInput works with data.frame but not with list of dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

I want to update a selectInput in an interactive rmarkdown shiny document depends of selection in a list of dataframe,but shiny give me this error. Warning: Error in [[: attempt to select less than one element in get1index

Examples. Change input$disp depends on selected cyl.

Example 1. Create a list of 3 data.frame split by cyl and select one by name.

````
    ---
title: "Test observe"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---



    ```{r echo=FALSE}

    datos <- mtcars
    datos <- split(datos, datos$cyl )
    un_cyl <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
    gears <- c(3,4,5)
    disp_list <- unique(mtcars$disp)


    inputPanel(
     selectInput("cyl", label = "cyl",
                  choices = un_cyl),
      selectInput("disp", label = "disp",
                  choices = disp_list,  selected = disp_list[1])
    )


    eventos_sel <- reactive({
      eventos <- datos[[input$cyl]]
      eventos
    })


    elegibles <- reactive({
      tmp <- eventos_sel()
      tmp <- unique(tmp$disp)
      return(tmp)
    })

    # hacer un updateSelectInput

    observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "disp", choices = elegibles())
      })


    renderPrint(elegibles())


    ```
````

Example 2. Same as example 1 but use subset the original data.frame instead of create a list. This example works but I need a list of dataframe in my real case.

````
---
title: "Test observe"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---



```{r echo=FALSE}

datos <- mtcars
# change from example 1 
# datos <- split(datos, datos$cyl ) 
un_cyl <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
gears <- c(3,4,5)
disp_list <- unique(mtcars$disp)


inputPanel(
 selectInput("cyl", label = "cyl",
              choices = un_cyl),
  selectInput("disp", label = "disp",
              choices = disp_list,  selected = disp_list[1])
)


eventos_sel <- reactive({
  # change from example 1 
  eventos <- datos[datos$cyl == input$cyl, ]
  eventos
})


elegibles <- reactive({
  tmp <- eventos_sel()
  tmp <- unique(tmp$disp)
  return(tmp)
})

# hacer un updateSelectInput

observe({
  updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "disp", choices = elegibles())
  })


renderPrint(elegibles())


```
````

Answer (score 0):

1. to refer to a specific data frame in the list, you must use a character, not a integer, even though their names are just a number
2. you have to check that `input$cyl` has a valid value before you use it so that you don't get an error (shiny seems to run that function before `input$cyl` has a valid value)

working code...

````
---
title: "Test observe"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
datos <- mtcars
datos <- split(datos, datos$cyl)
un_cyl <- unique(mtcars$cyl)
gears <- c(3,4,5)
disp_list <- unique(mtcars$disp)

inputPanel(
  selectInput("cyl", label = "cyl",
              choices = un_cyl),
  selectInput("disp", label = "disp",
              choices = disp_list,  selected = disp_list[1])
)

eventos_sel <- reactive({
  cylname <- as.character(input$cyl)
  if (length(cylname) == 0) cylname <- "6"
  eventos <- datos[[cylname]]
})

elegibles <- reactive({
  tmp <- eventos_sel()
  tmp <- unique(tmp$disp)
  return(tmp)
})

# hacer un updateSelectInput
observe({
  updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "disp", choices = elegibles())
})

renderPrint(elegibles())
```
````